# Get touch location of screen in a spritekit game

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, uitouch

i have a sprite kit game and im trying to know if the user has touch the left, right or middle of the screen (25/50/25)

At the moment when i touch the very left side of the screen, it says im touching -450 on the x axis when it should be 0. I assume its getting my touch position relative to the scene and as the achor point starts 450 pixels to the right, gives me -450 when i touch 0.

As this is a side scroller, moving the achor wont work and i need the touch location of the screen:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>,with event: UIEvent?){
    var touchLeft : Bool = false
    var touchRight : Bool = false
    var touchMiddle : Bool = false

    for touch in (touches) {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)

        if(location.x < self.size.width/4){
            touchLeft = true
            print("Left")
        } else if(location.x > ((self.size.width/4) * 3)){
            touchRight = true
            print("Right")
        } else {
            touchMiddle = true
            print("Middle")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @vacawama, you are confusing `Views` with `Nodes/Scenes`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost had it,  just factor in negative numbers.

In case you were not aware, 0 is the center by default for SKScene. This is because the default anchor point is 0.5,0.5.

Since you are using the camera to handle your scrolling,  you want to use 
`touch.location(in: self.camera)` so that you are always touching relative to where the camera is and not where the scene is.

So just change your code to as follows:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>,with event: UIEvent?){
    var touchLeft : Bool = false
    var touchRight : Bool = false
    var touchMiddle : Bool = false

    for touch in (touches) {
        let location = touch.location(in: self.camera)

        if(location.x < -self.size.width/4){
            touchLeft = true
            print("Left")
        } else if(location.x > ((self.size.width/4))){
            touchRight = true
            print("Right")
        } else {  //x is between -width / 4 and width / 4
            touchMiddle = true
            print("Middle")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesnt factor in the camera scrolling to the right. I have tried adding the cameras x location to the touch location which is still not working

Comment: Im thinking of doing it in gameController.swift if thats possible. Then when i add more levels i can use it from there too

Comment: You need to clarify that behavior when asking your questions, use `touch.location(in:self.camera)`

Comment: i did mention it was a side scroller in the question but yeh self.camera works great, thanks :)

Comment: @RachelDockter, many ways to create a side scroller,  it would be foolish for me to assume how you are creating your side scroller.  E.G. I could move the scene to create the effect of scrolling.